# Knock Out data binding not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having a problem with the knockout.js library.  I am using the following code, and the databindings are not executing properly.

HTML Code:

```
<form data-bind="submit: LogintoSite">UserId:
    <input type="email" data-bind="value: UserLogin" />Password:
    <input type="password" data-bind="value: Password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</Button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var LoginScreenViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.UserLogin = ko.observable("Hello");
    self.Password = ko.observable("");
    self.LoginToSite = function () {
        alert("You Pushed the button");
    };
};
ko.ApplyBindings(new LoginScreenViewModel());
```

The project itself is in MVC 4 but i have tried this code on jsfiddle as well and it does not work there either.  I can't figure out why it will not work.  I am assuming this is something simple i forgot in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what the error is and how your databindings are not executing properly? If you already made a jsfiddle, can you post a link to it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should use applyBindings instead of ApplyBindings; also are you referencing knockout.js ?

Comment: yeah the applyBindings fixed it thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `LoginToSite` in your viewmodel while in your databindings you have `LogintoSite`, notice the lowercase "t".

As somebody else mentioned in the comments I think you should also be calling `applyBindings` instead of `ApplyBindings`